# datetimepicker is not working after submit

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, datetimepicker

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $(function () {
                $("#<%= tbTime.ClientID %>").datetimepicker({
                    format: 'LT'
                });
            });
        })
    </script>
```

```html
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
     <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                  <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicdker3'>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="tbTime" Width="300" runat="server" class="form-control input-sm"></asp:TextBox>
    </ContentTemplate>
    </UpdatePanel>
```

This is working fine but after submit, the datetimepicker is not showing

Answer (score 0):

This is because the [Partial-Page Rendering](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386573.aspx), but there is a way to call that code *every time* that a partial rendering occurs, and is using the **pageLoad function**

```
function pageLoad() { 
    $("#<%= tbTime.ClientID %>").datetimepicker({
        format: 'LT'
    });
}
```